# Does the CPU stay awake when the device is charging?

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

The documentation mentions that 6.0+ Android devices will not enter doze mode while charging, but what about regular sleep mode? I could not find anything that indicates that the CPU will turn off when it is plugged to a charger.

From some testing I've done it seems that the device is fine without the CPU `WakeLock` when running background processes, but I want to make sure; because it could be a case of another app holding a `WakeLock`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android sleeps when no wake-lock is active no matter what thread or process you have to execute even when charging and some modified os like miui and other Chinese roms have aggressive cpu sleep, so it's better use wake lock or Other alternative check for more info here [https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock].

Doze is more aggressive about preserving your battery life by putting your phone in a low-power.
In this state apps background processes execute in batches, this might have issues executing in background.

And from version 8.0 Google restrict background tasks even more

Comment: The question at hand is whether or not this behavior is affected by the device being charged. The only reason I am asking this is because from tests I've done, tasks (both background & foreground, both Oreo and below) were actually being completed when the device had its screen turned off for a long time (without the charger, tasks fail at about a 15-10 minute mark).

Comment: I noticed you edited your answer to include that Android will sleep even if the device is plugged into a charger. I am curious to know how do you know this to be true? I have found no documentation about this.

Comment: Is this still the case in latest Android in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

From my testing with battery historian, CPU will not sleep if phone is charging.

Same for doze, it will not enter doze if phone is charging (I have a patch to force doze even while charging).

Comment: +1 [Doze mode doesn't engage while a battery-powered device is plugged into a power charger.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/platform_mgmt#detection)